# Abbreviation of the word "example"

Tags: abbreviations

How would the word "example" be abbreviated? I think "ex." is reserved for "exercise"; what about "expl."?

To be clear, I am asking about the word "example" specifically, not an abbreviation for the phrase "for example".

If I cite a book, let us call it BK, I would write [BK, Example 1]. But I do not want to write "Example" but an abbreviation of it.

Comment: It’s ***e.g.***

Comment: But this is more 'for example' isn't it? I want to shorten 'Example 1'.

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Please [edit] to clarify your question, such as by adding one or two sample sentences.

Comment: use the plural form followed by the list of examples **Examples** 1. blah, blah, 2. blah, blah, 3. blah, blah. **You need to provide us with one or two sample sentences** (the recent edit is not enough)  if you want users to provide you with the best answers.

Comment: Yes you are right, I edited my case.

Comment: I won't cast my vote to close the question, but can't you provide a full sentence, or explain why you need to say "BK example 1."  What's wrong with "The following are examples of XYZ: BK 1, BK 2, BK 3 etc.

Comment: If this is a question about naming a computer file, directory or something, you can write whatever you like: ex. xpl. e.g. and so on.

Answer (score 2):

From Collins English Dictionary published in 1979:

> ex. abbreviation for: 1-examination 2-examined 3-example 4-except(ed) 5-exception 6-exchange 7-excursion 8-executed 9-executive 10-express 11-extra

The context, therefore, in which you wish to use the abbreviation ex. (don't forget the dot!) is critical otherwise people may misunderstand what the abbreviation stands for.

Also, don't use the abbreviation Ex. because that comes from the Biblical abbreviation for the book of Exodus.

Comment: I'd say that 'Ex.' would be acceptable if the "Example" bit is so capitalized in the BK being cited. Context would continue to make it clear even in that case.

Comment: Lesley, is it correct that lowercase _ex._ is OK? And is there a convention to use something like _exs._ for plural examples, the same way as _pp._ for _pages_?

Comment: @john c. j. Lower case ex. is the standard.  My dictionary does not show exs. inthe case of plural examples, so I really don't know.